# filter string with quotes in Spark dataframe column

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF with this data:

```
--------+------------------------------------------+
|recType |value                                     |
+--------+------------------------------------------+
|{"id": 1|{"id": 1, "user_id": 100, "price": 50}    |
...
```

I can filter recType with `contains`, but how to do with `===` and quotes? I seem to get some error every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that columns here are strings. If so, [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#from_json(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
function can parse them into structure.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType, IntegerType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json

val recTypeSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("id", IntegerType, true)
))
val valueSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("id", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("user_id", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("price", IntegerType, true)
))

val parsedDf = df
    .withColumn("recType", from_json($"recType", recTypeSchema))
    .withColumn("value", from_json($"value", valueSchema))

parsedDf.printSchema
root
 |-- recType: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- price: integer (nullable = true)


parsedDf.filter($"recType.id" === 1).show
+-------+------------+
|recType|       value|
+-------+------------+
|    {1}|{1, 100, 50}|
+-------+------------+
```

Comment: True, but I am looking for the filter against the recType. Upvote anyway.

Comment: I don't get then what "filter against recType" means. Can you explain how exactly you want to apply the filter?

Comment: Did you want just `df.filter($"recType" === """{"id": 1}""")`?

Comment: I can convert string col to json, if DS. Need the filter.

Comment: Subset of  records with same json schema, others with other record type have another schema.

Comment: If that works that is what i want.

Comment: I will look when i get up.

Comment: For some reason - may be needing glasses - I had a slight variation, the comment is correct.